# If $B$ is open and $B \subset A$ then $B\subset A^◦$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $B$ is open and $B \subset A$ then  $B\subset A^◦$

I know a demonstration but it is very long. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the definition of "interior of a set" that you know?

Comment: You understand by $\subset$ the relation $\subseteq$, right? For $\subsetneq$ this is not true...

Comment: $A^◦ = \{x \in X | x\quad \text{is a interior point}\}$, and also that $A$ is union of open balls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x\in B$, then, since $B$ is open and $B\subset A$, $x$ is an interior point of $A$. In other words, $x\in\mathring A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

By maximality of the interior we can say that if there is an open set that is include in the set then the open set is in the interior

Answer (score 0):

The interior of a set is the largest open set contained in it.  Or, it is the union of all open sets contained in it.